# Keep the first 3 decimals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in order to calculate `1 - (value2 / value1)`.

```
select ID 
     , 1 - (value2 / value1) as value3
from table
group by ID
```

How can I make it to have the first **3** decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`truncate`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate), if you *don't need rounding*:

```sql
truncate(1 - (value2 / value1), 3) as value3
```

*Otherwise* use [`round`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round):

```sql
round(1 - (value2 / value1), 3) as value3
```

*P.S.: You need to either include this calculated column in the `group by` clause or aggregate it somehow in the `select` clause.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function in MySQL to cast the value as a decimal. When you create a decimal, you specify the precision (maximum number of digits) and you can also specify the maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). For simplicity, let's say we limit to 10 total digits with three decimal places:

```
SELECT id, CAST((1 - (value2/value1)) AS DECIMAL(10, 3)) AS value3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Note that this will keep a *maximum* of three digits to the right of the decimal point. It will ignore unnecessary zeros so you may see values like -1.5 instead of -1.500.